# Print Document opened in QLPreviewController with Right menu button?

Tags: objective-c, printing, ios6.1, qlpreviewcontroller

I have opened the document (PDF) in QLPreviewController. I want to print that document on clicking right button on the top of the screen. I need code example to print it. I don't want email option over there. thats why I cannot use UIDocumentInteractionController.

Answer (score 1):

With QLPreviewController, what you see is what you get.

You are either stuck with the share button and all the options it gives (print, email, etc) or you rewrite that button yourself using UIActivityViewController.

In your instance of QLPreviewController, you can overwrite that button in viewDidAppear by doing :

```
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil];
```

Note this just removes the button altogether but you can create your own button and add your own sharing options to it as well. See [this](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/steven-beyers/cocoaconf-dc-recap-sharing-uiactivityviewcontroller) for more info.